# Can't use an array as default values for Ruby Hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I was adding items to a Hash key. I was expecting to get a structure like this:

```
{ 
  'a' : [1],
  'b' : [2, 3, 4]
}
```

I used an Array to initialize the Hash.

```
irb> hash = Hash.new([])
 => {}
```

Then started using it:

```
irb> hash['a'] << 1
 => [1] 
irb> hash['b'] << 2
 => [1, 2]
```

But it turns out:

```
irb> hash
 => {}
```

Comment: Are you unsure about the output you are seeing? Or what the Hash actually contains? It is unclear what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
hash = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}
hash['a'] << 1 # => [1]
hash['b'] << 2 # => [2]
```

The reason you got your unexpected results is that you specified an empty array as default value, but the same array is used; no copy is done. The right way is to initialize the value with a new empty array, as in my code.

Comment: +1 "you specified an empty array as default value, but the same array is used". Bingo!

Comment: What?! This is really strange to me. When you use a string that string is not being re-used. The string might be some sort of value type, but I thought "everything" was an object in Ruby. Why the difference between strings and other objects?

Comment: @Cort3z: Not sure what you mean. Maybe this can help show there is no difference: `a = b = 'foo'; a.replace 'bar'; b # => 'bar'`

Comment: Maybe I was unclear: What I meant was that I think it is strange that when you do `Hash.new([])` it uses the same array object, but when you do `Hash.new("string")` it does not use the same string.

Comment: @Cort3z: It will use the same string. `h = Hash.new("don't do this"); h[0].upcase!; h[1] # => "DON'T DO THIS"`

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune Now I see what is going on. I was doing `h = Hash.new("W"); h["test"] = "data"; p h["a"] #=> "W"`. I guess it reassigns the object for `h["test"]` only, and not actually change the object.

Answer (score 4):

The [constructor](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/new/class) you used stores `[]` as the default value to return when accessing keys that are unknown. Since `Array#<<` modifies its receiver *in place* this initially empty array grows.

To explain in more detail:

When you do `hash['a'] << 1` this is what happens:

1. `hash` looks to see if there is a key named `'a'`
2. It finds that no, there is no such key.
3. It looks if it has stored a default value to return.
4. Since you constructed it with `Hash.new([])` it does have such a value, `[]` and it returns that.
5. Now `[] << 1` is evaluated and this means that hash now stores `[1]` as the value to return when a previously unencountered key is requested.

If what you want is to store the key value pair instead use the third form of the constructor with a block:

```
hash = Hash.new{|h, key| h[key] = []}
```

Answer (score 2):

`hash['a'] << 1` and `hash['b'] << 2` isn't correct syntax for creating a key/value pair. You have to use `=` for that:

```
hash['a'] = []
hash['a'] << 1

hash['b'] = []
hash['b'] << 2
```

That should give you the hash `{'a' : [1], 'b' : [2]}`

Answer (score 1):

This is *exactly* the behavior that you would expect to see.

You never add anything to the `Hash`, therefore the `Hash` is completely empty. When you look up a key, that key will never exist, therefore it returns the default value, which you have specified to be an `Array`.

So, you look up the key `'a'`, which doesn't exist, and thus returns the `Array` you specified as the default value. Then, you call `<<` on that `Array`, which appends a value (`1`) to it.

Next, you look up the key `'b'`, which also doesn't exist, and thus returns the `Array` you specified as the default value, which now contains the element `1` you added earlier. Then, you call `<<` on that `Array`, appending the value `2` to it.

You end up with a `Hash` that is still empty, since you never added anything to it. The default value of the `Hash` is now an array containing the values `1` and `2`.

The output you are seeing is because IRb always prints the result of the last expression that was evaluated. The last expression in your example is calling `<<` on the `Array`. `<<` returns its receiver, which then is the return value of the entire expression and thus what IRb prints out.

Comment: It does exactly what you ask, and not at all what you mean!