# array as value in hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I want to have a hash whose key is a string and the value is an array. I tried it the following way:

```
h = Hash.new([]) # => {} 
h["one"]         # => [] 
h["two"]         # => [] 
h["one"].push 1  # => [1] 
h["one"]         # => [1] 
h["two"]         # => [1] //why did it assign it to h["two"] also??
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: That is the correct way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use an array as default values for Ruby Hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488853/cant-use-an-array-as-default-values-for-ruby-hash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
h['one']
h
# => { 'one' => [] }
h['two'] << 12
h
# => { 'one' => [], 'two' => [12] }
```

Which is more verbose and (IMO) reads nicer.

Answer (score 4):

You get this behavior because `[]` that you passed into `new` method isn't copied but referenced in all unset hash keys. So `h['one']` references the same object as `h['two']`. So if you modify object referenced by `h['one']` (using `push` method), `h['two']` will also be modified.

The correct way to set default value which will be initialized for every single hash key is to use block:

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```